# Docker Compose/Stack config writeable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

we are using dockers config feature to push configs to the different nodes in the cluster (swarm). We do this by specifying it in the docker-compose file. Unfortunately, this results in the file being read-only. Is there a way to resolve this or to push the custom config to the servers in a way that the docker container can still overwrite parts of it?

e.g.

```
  zookeeperDelta:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zookeeperDelta
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
    configs:
      - source: zookeeper_cfg
        target: /conf/zoo.cfg
        gid: '1000'
        uid: '1000'
        mode: 0777
    volumes:
      - /var/zookeeper/logs:/logs
      - /var/zookeeper/data:/data
      - /var/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_LOG4J_PROP: INFO,ROLLINGFILE
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeperAlpha:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zookeeperBeta:2888:3888;2181 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == zookeeperDelta
```

Comment: Is this for the `zookeeper_cfg` ? I see you already update the `mode` parameter for the config.

Comment: @nitishagar yes, unfortunately, it is still read-only

Answer (score 1):

The documentation specifies that configs are not writable. Excerpt below:

> Configs cannot be writable because they are mounted in a temporary
>   filesystem, so if you set the writable bit, it is ignored.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

You can possibly **rotate config**, following is one example: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#example-rotate-a-config

Comment: Thanks, do you see any way of achieving writeability where we push the config from the swarm manager? (The container overwrites parts of the config with the cluster settings.)